# Fix routing in raspbian 10 (make it persistent)

Tags: routing, raspbian, route

I have a raspberry pi running raspbian and I want to use it as a wired router (DHCP server on eth0 and DHCP client on wlan0). It starts to work but I have a problem that I can't fix. My routing table get broken at regular intervals.

When booting, I have:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route show
default via 192.168.20.254 dev eth0 src 192.168.20.254 metric 202 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.31 metric 303 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.31 metric 303 
192.168.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.20.254 metric 202
```

I fix it with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip route delete default via 192.168.20.254 dev eth0
```

and I get (which works well):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.31 metric 303 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.31 metric 303 
192.168.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.20.254 metric 202
```

But after a while (and after reboot) it returns to its previous state.

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is configured like this:

```
hostname

clientid

persistent

option rapid_commit

option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu

require dhcp_server_identifier

slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.20.254/24
static routers=192.168.20.254
static domain_name_servers=208.67.222.222 207.67.220.220
```

`/etc/network/interfaces/` is basically empty.

I have read through a lot of articles but I can't find one that answers my request. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dhcpd is adding the problem route because you have told it to do that.

Remove the line

```
static routers=192.168.20.254
```

and your problem should go away.

Comment: I suspected than it was reappearing due to the DHCP lease renewal. Thank you !